# Alternative Text for Copy and Paste / Machine Reading

Tags: resume, accessibility, extract

I'm trying to have the best of both worlds and use a nifty 2-column latex resume template (altacv), while also creating something that parses nicely via `CTRL+A, CTRL+C, CTRL+V` or when fed into an Applicant Tracking System.

Is there a way to use something like accsupp's "ActualText" to have a version of text which is visible to machines be different from that displayed to human readers? Perhaps by converting the visual resume to an image and then underlaying single-column text below it?

I'm fine with solutions that require entering the document contents twice if converting the resume text is too complex.